# The PID's initial position seems to be ignored everywhere. Why?

Tags: microcontroller, control, pid-controller

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller), you will find this definition of the PID (position form)

$$u(t)=K_p\:e(t) + K_i\int_{0}^{t} e(\tau)\:d\tau + K_d\:\frac{d}{dt}e(t)$$

In the same article, when you [learn about the Velocity Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#Discrete_implementation) of this equation, the main advantage stated is that it will remove the \$u_0\$ from the position form.

$$u(t)=K_p\:e(t) + K_i\int_{0}^{t} e(\tau)\:d\tau + K_d\:\frac{d}{dt}e(t) + u_0$$

Why is \$u_0\$ not mentioned for the entire article (and honestly in most internet resources)    ?

EDIT:
This textbook seems to agree with Wikipedia about the value of the Velocity form.
[image]

Comment: Because the amount I depress the accelerator on my car now has nothing to do with the speed I was at when I left home two hours ago.

Comment: @Transistor Sorry if I was not clear: I understand the value of the Velocity form.
I don't understand why \$u_0\$ is never mentioned until that point.

Answer (score 1):

Both your formulas are actually **position form**, with only difference in steady-state offset that *might* be beneficial for some very specific applications.

For example, a thermal plant with constant heat loss may use an offset to compensate for this loss, so that the actual PID control only operates in narrow range for better precision.

Velocity form does not use U<sub>0</sub>, it uses U<sub>n-1</sub>.

The Wikipedia article that you refer to derives velocity form to use it in the discrete implementation example. See equation beginning with:  U(t<sub>k</sub>) = U(t<sub>k-1</sub>) + . . .

Unfortunately the note right under that equation is quite confusing. My guess, what they wanted to say was "*velocity form prevents the output from wild jumps when any of the loop parameters changes abruptly*". This is because control signal at time (t) is based on previous control at time (t-1) and a relatively small difference between them.

You can find good information on the difference between position and velocity forms in this whitepaper from Rockwell Automation: [Perform Common Process
Loop Control Algorithms](https://literature.rockwellautomation.com/idc/groups/literature/documents/wp/logix-wp008_-en-p.pdf)

Comment: Got it. thank you. As a follow-up: If \$u_0\$ might be useful only for some very specific applications, why would you use the velocity form?

Comment: Umm... did you really get it? U0 has nothing to do with velocity form. See the link I've added at the end.

Comment: let me rephrase that: the only reason stated by Wikipedia to use the velocity form instead of the position form is the absence of \$u_0$\. My question: Is this really the only reason?

Comment: Once again, the second formula in your question (with U0) is **not** a velocity form. It is the same position form but with offset added to command. The real velocity formula in Wikipedia article is _above_ that one, and it begins with "U(tk)=...". As you can see it is _very different_ from the position form. You can find simpler notation in the article at the link I've provided.

Comment: As for the reasons to use velocity form, here are two: 1) velocity form does not have integral for I term, because accumulated errors are already reflected in U(k-1). This reduces issues with integral windup. 2) velocity form does not use error differential in D term directly, it uses the difference between current and previous error differentials. This reduces derivative kick when setpoint changes. Note that better way of dealing with derivative kick is to use derivative on input instead of derivative on error.